# syzygy of a generalized cohen-macaulay module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $R$ be a local, noetherian ring of dimension $d$ and suppose it is generalized cohen-macaulay. Is it true that For any finitely generated $ R $-module $ M $, which is  maximal generalized cohen-macaulay, $ \Omega^d M $ is maximal generalized cohen-macaulay.

Note that, $ M $(always noetherian over the local ring $ R $) is called generalized cohen-macaulay if for $  i = 0, 1,2 , ..., dim(M) - 1 $,   $ H_{\frak m}^i(M) $ are noetherian modules.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a generalized Cohen-Macaulay module?